# Setting Variable as Integer Once

Tags: python

I'm a beginner in coding, currently using sikuli as a tool and learning python in a fun way.

I asked my good friend who knows C++, he told me that what I wanna do can exactly be written in C++ as

```
for (int x=0; x < 10)
```

Setting the variable as integer, and having increment set in a condition. I'm not using 
`in range(0,10)` is because I don't want the variable to be increased if my condition is not meet.
So how do I set the variable x as 0 or integer only once at the top so that my function can start looping and get increment correctly when the condition is met?

Comment: Perhaps this is entirely subjective, but I personally think using sikuli to learn Python is very dangerous, especially if it's your very first programming language and you don't have much experience. You may end up picking up bad habits and fail to understand what you are really doing. I would very much recommend that you start off with simple non-GUI programs first and use the Python tutorial to help guide you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are asking about a while loop. This code will exist if `x` reaches 10, but a condition, which you haven't mentioned will need to be met to increment `x`:

```
x = 0
while x < 10:
    if condition:
        x += 1
```

Comment: Thanks @lego Not sure what's causing it to not work before, I had `x = 0` and used `for x in range(0,10)` also `x = x + 1` in the condition. But every time it prints the variable, I only see `x = 0`. Do you know what seems to be the problem here? Seems I haven't yet properly distinguish while and for loop. Thanks for the solution.

Comment: Btw to paint it in better picture, my code before were

`x = 0
for x in range (0,10):
    if condition:
        x = x + 1`